# Using purrr and functions to perform linear regressions on a number of variables with random errors

Tags: r, function, regression, purrr

This is what my data looks like:

```
dataSet <- data.frame(study_id=c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3),
                      Timepoint=c(1,6,12,18,1,6,12,18,1,6,12,18),
                      Secretor=c(0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0),
                      Gene1=c(1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4),
                      Gene2=c(3,4,5,6,3,4,5,6,3,4,5,6),
                      Gene3=c(4,5,6,7,4,5,6,7,4,5,6,7),
                      Gene4=c(6,7,8,9,6,7,8,9,6,7,8,9))
```

I have successfully used purrr to generate many exploratory ggplots using the following function:

```
library(tidyverse)

stat_sum_df_all <- function(fun, geom="pointrange", ...) {
  stat_summary(fun.data=fun, geom=geom, ...)
}

plot_fun = function(x, y) {
  ggplot(data = dataSet, aes(x = .data[[x]], y = .data[[y]], group = Secretor, colour = Secretor)) +
    stat_summary(geom = "line", fun.data = median_hilow) +
    stat_sum_df_all("median_hilow", fun.args=(conf.int = 0.5), linetype = "solid") +
    theme_bw()
} 

genelist = names(dataSet)[4:7]
Timepoint = names(dataSet)[2]

all_plots = map(genelist,
                ~map(Timepoint, plot_fun, y = .x) )
```

Now what I would like to do is put the p-values of linear regressions in the title of the plots. The formula of my regression is this:

```
library(lmerTest)
fit <- lmer(genelist ~ Timepoint*Secretor + (1|study_id), data=dataSet)
```

However, I can't figure out how to similarly create a function like the one I did for the plots to run this regression for each gene. Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: `all_plots` code does not run for me. It returns an error `Error in map(Timepoint, plot_fun, y = .x) : object 'Timepoint' not found`. Same for `lmer` code `Error in model.frame.default(data = dataSet, drop.unused.levels = TRUE,  : 
  variable lengths differ (found for 'Timepoint')`

Comment: Your script doesn't work. Pleate make sure that your script is complete if you want to receive an answer to your question.

Comment: @RonakShah my apologies, edited - it should run now.

Comment: `lmer(genelist ~ Timepoint*Secretor + (1|study_id), data=dataSet)` this still doesn't work returns `Error in model.frame.default(data = dataSet, drop.unused.levels = TRUE,  : 
  variable lengths differ (found for 'Timepoint')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got assistance on reddit, here was the solution, thanks everyone for your help.

```
my_fitting_function <- function(gene) {
  f <- paste0(gene, " ~ Timepoint*Secretor + (1|study_id)")
  fit <- lmer(f, data = dataSet)
  return(fit)
}
models <- purrr::map(genelist, my_fitting_function)
```